# Как правильно настроить раздачу интернет в локальной сети на Zyxel Keenetic EXTRA?

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизатор, шлюз

В конторе купили интернет центр Zyxel Keenetic Extra (https://zyxel.ru/keenetic-extra). К провайдеру цепляемся через PPoE.

Как настроить в домашней сети раздачу интерната то же по PPoE через этот роутер?

Очень не хочеться поднимать в локальной сети PPoE сервер и заводить на него интернет, а потом уже с него производить раздачу интернета клиентам.

Буду признателен любой информации по теме.

Comment: Zyxel Keenetic выпускается только в России, потому что на глобальном сайте я не нашел таких продуктов. Жаль так же, что версия EXTRA не поддерживает VPN сервер для домашней сети, в отличие от версии ULTRA.

Comment: Советую сдать обратно в магазин, да купить вместо него Mikrotik hEX, либо если есть стойка, то RB2011iL-IN - они поставленную вами задачу без каких-либо проблем выполнят. Да и дешевле они.  Zyxel Keenetic Extra разрабатывали для простой раздачи интернета в квартире, не более - основную часть стоимости там составляет внешний дизайн премиум-класса.

Comment: Проблема в том, что не я принимаю решение о покупке чего либо в этой конторе. Значить придется использовать промежуточный маршрутизатор и на нем поднимать все сервисы, что будут нужны. Спасибо, Сергей.